# converting a fragment into an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity(RecoveryActivity) which has a fragment(RecoveryFragment). A button click calls this activity in which RecoveryFragment is shown. I just want to directly call RecoveryFragment as an activity. How to convert this fragment into an activity. Noob here ! Any help would be deeply appreciated.

RecoveryActivity

```
public class RecoveryActivity extends ActivityBase {

private static final String TAG = "password_recovery_activity";

Toolbar mToolbar;

Fragment fragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recovery);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "currentFragment");

    } else {

        fragment = new RecoveryFragment();
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_body, fragment).commit();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "currentFragment", fragment);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home: {

            finish();
            return true;
        }

        default: {

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }}}
```

RecoveryFragment

```
public class RecoveryFragment extends Fragment implements Constants {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

Button mContinueBtn;
EditText mEmail;
String email;

private Boolean loading = false;

public RecoveryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRetainInstance(true);

    initpDialog();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recovery, container, false);

    if (loading) {

        showpDialog();
    }

    mEmail = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.PasswordRecoveryEmail);

    mContinueBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.PasswordRecoveryBtn);

    mContinueBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            email = mEmail.getText().toString();

            if (!App.getInstance().isConnected()) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.msg_network_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                Helper helper = new Helper();

                if (helper.isValidEmail(email)) {

                    recovery();

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getText(R.string.error_email), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}

public void onDestroyView() {

    super.onDestroyView();

    hidepDialog();
}

protected void initpDialog() {

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_loading));
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
}

protected void showpDialog() {

    if (!pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.show();
}

protected void hidepDialog() {

    if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public void recovery() {

    loading = true;

    showpDialog();

    CustomRequest jsonReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, METHOD_ACCOUNT_RECOVERY, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {

                        if (!response.getBoolean("error")) {


                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getText(R.string.msg_password_reset_link_sent), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            getActivity().finish();

                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getText(R.string.msg_no_such_user_in_bd), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } finally {

                        loading = false;

                        hidepDialog();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            loading = false;

            hidepDialog();

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getText(R.string.error_data_loading), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("clientId", CLIENT_ID);
            params.put("email", email);

            return params;
        }
    };

    App.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}}
```

Comment: why do you want to convert your fragment to activity? Use Fragment, its a good practice. But you can add fragment_recovery layout to your your activity directly.  Use <include> tag to include layout in container_body layout directly

Answer (score 0):

You start by extending AppCompatActivity instead of Fragment

`public class RecoveryActivity extends AppCompatActivity` (this is your fragment but I renamed it RecoveryActivity. You shouldn't cause you'd have 2 activities with the same name.Let's say it's called RecoveryActivityNew. The instructions below are not for what you named as RecoveryActivity but for the RecoveryFragment piece of code.

Then you remove the methods such as onAttach() and onDetach() which are only relevant to a fragment. Get rid of onDestroyView. Remove onCreateView() and all the code that is in there, put it in onCreate()

Now because you don't have a fragment, you reference a view like this:

`mContinueBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PasswordRecoveryBtn);`

Just like you referenced the toolbar in the activity (you lose the rootView).

Also, in displaying the Toast for example, you don't use the getActivity() method but use `this` or `RecoveryActivity.this`:

`Toast.makeText(RecoveryActivity.this, R.string.msg_network_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Get rid of the constructor `public RecoveryFragment()`

And don't forget to declare your new activity in the app's Manifest file.

```
<activity
        android:name=".RecoveryActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.your.packagename.RecoveryActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried doing something like this as you said but I am making some error I guess. I declared it in manifest too. It would be very helpful if you can show me how to do it in the above code. Learning android so didn't get much what you said above. I will Be thankful